# Can I crearte multiple associated database rows with one database query in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

```
:doctor has_many :appointments
:doctor has_many :patients, through: :appointments

:appointment belongs_to :doctor
:appointment belongs_to :patient

:patient has_many :appointments
:patient has_many :doctors, through: :appointments
```

:appointments has three columns, :patient_id, :doctor_id, :location. Now for a specific doctor I can create a patient and its related appointment with one query using

```
doctor.patients.create!(name: "John Smith")
```

However this leaves the :location column in the related :appointment equal to nil. Is there a way to specify the :location in the above command? I want to create the patient and related appointment (and specify the :location) with only one query. Is that possible? I tried to guess the right solution like the following, but it didn't work:

```
doctor.patients.create!(name: "John Smith", appointment: {location: "hospital"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointments
end
```

And your code should work with small change:

```
doctor.patients.create!(name: "John Smith", appointments_attributes: {location: "hospital"})
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I receive an error saying:

column patient_id is not unique: INSERT INTO "appointment" ("patient_id", "created_at", "doctor_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?).

Does that mean we can't do this?